# viewpagerindicator: listview empty in fragment empty on second time showing

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I've a NavigationDrawer to start fragments. I've a fragment with 4 tabs from `TabPageIndicator` with fragments which contains a listview.

If I click the entry in the menu again which launches the fragment, the elements are gone. Sometimes if I switch between them they are gone too. I also have to swipe sometimes to get them back.

**ArchivFragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archiv, viewGroup, false);
    
    List<String> titles=new ArrayList<String>();
    titles.add(getString(R.string.category_animal));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.category_earth));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.category_water));
    titles.add(getString(R.string.category_air));
    
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new ArchivTabAdapter(getFragmentManager(), titles);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    
    return view;
}
```

**ArchivTabAdapter** *using from an example*

```
public class ArchivTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<String> tabs;

    public ArchivTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> tabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArchivListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position % tabs.size()).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }
}
```

**ArchivListFragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.archiv_list, viewGroup, false);
    
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
    
    ArrayList<Item> al = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    al = getArrayListToApply(filter);
    
    lv.setAdapter(new ArchivArrayAdapter(getActivity(), al));
    
    return view;
}
```

**ArchivArrayAdapter**

similar to `ArchivTabAdapter`

### update 1

it seems, that I've to scroll over all items (especially the last one) to get the others back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ArchivTabAdapter**
[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746652/fragment-is-blank-the-second-time-it-is-viewed)

change from
`android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`