# Maintain data ViewPager fragment inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

[image][image]I have an activity withs 2 button. each button display a certain fragment into  main activity. The first fragment(FragA) is simple Red colored layout. The second fragment (FragB) contains ViewPager with Sub-Fragments (FragX + FragZ). First SubFragment (FragX) displays data from database into list. When I first view this fragment (FragX), list is udpated with records properly. But when i go to the Red Fragment (FragA), then go back to Fragmet (FragX), records are NOT displayed into the list.
NB. Data is updated into the list by CursorAdapter, that gets data from  SQLITE database

How to view this error:
- Run application , project is save to this link : https://www.4shared.com/s/f48I7CNy1ea
- Click "Add" button into the main activity twice or 3 times to add records to database
- Click FRB to view FragmentB >>  a BLUE fragment display, with viewpager , the layout shows list with records that have been added to databse (eg 2 or 3 records)
 - Click on FRAA to display FragmentA , >> will display Fragment A (RED Fragment)
- Click Back FRB >> BLUE Fragment is displayed... but list will not show any records

Answer (score 0):

To those who may face same issue , I managed to solve this by replacing getFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager() in the parent fragment. This parent fragment was instancing an

Solution was found into below question :
[Fragment in ViewPager using FragmentPagerAdapter is blank the second time it is viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746652/fragment-in-viewpager-using-fragmentpageradapter-is-blank-the-second-time-it-is?rq=1)