# Viewpager view appears and shows blank after fraction of seconds

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with 9 fragments in Activity(using FragmentPagerAdapter).When I open a fragment with one index update,view will work properly,but when I want to come from last fragment to 3rd fragment I am updating the viewpager.currentItem to 2. In this case 3rd fragment view will appear and after 2-3 seconds view will disappear.
It happens only on lower end devices.

Comment: Share your code as well.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746652/fragment-in-viewpager-using-fragmentpageradapter-is-blank-the-second-time-it-is/22677595