# Viewpager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter + Fragment not working

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager

I have a FragmentList with some items. If I click an item the appropriate Fragment will open which contains a Viewpager. No problem so far but if I go back to the List and click the item again the method getItem(int position) is not called anymore.
Here a link with a similar problem:
[Display fragment viewpager within a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700226/display-fragment-viewpager-within-a-fragment)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_runtime, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    return view; 
  }

class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position) {

        return muxbusTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int location) {

        return muxbusFragmentList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return muxbusTitles.length;
    }

}

    return view;

}
```

**Edit:**
If someone is interested,the solution was  to extends from PagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdpater because the Viewpager is already in a Fragment..

Answer (score 0):

I did have similar problem and after scratching my head for quite some time i made an my **own understanding (assumption)** that `ViewPager` is keeping the reference of its *child fragments* into memory even the hosted `Fragment or Activity` is destroyed (didn't tested with Activity). So i wrote this method `freeFragmentsFromViewPager()`. You need to call it from `onDestroy()` of your `Fragment`.

```
     /**
     * This method free the child fragments from ViewPager as ViewPager keeps the reference
     * of child fragments into memory and next time when you again come to visit view pager it won't show the fragment layout
     * because it has the reference to the fragment whilst the fragment's view was already destroyed.
     */
    private void freeFragmentsFromViewPager()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.fragments.length; i++)
        {
            Fragment fragment = TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.fragments[i];

            if(fragment != null)
            {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.fragments[i] = null;
            }       
        }   
    }
```

And this is my Adapter code

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public static final int NUM_TABS = 3;

    public static Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[NUM_TABS];

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Log.e("TabsFragmentPagerAdapter", "getItem");

        Fragment fragment = TabsFragmentFactory.newInstace(position);

        fragments[position] = fragment;

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return NUM_TABS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
    {
        return TabsFragmentFactory.getName(position);
    }
```