# Fragment Content not shown after back navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a fragment that has a sliding tab layout and a view pager with 5 tabs.
I start on tab 1, then, i push a different fragment to the back stack, replacing the fragment with the tabs.
When, i now navigate back, the fragment with the tabs appears, but the first two tabs are empty (tab/fragment are not shown, but the views are created). If i navigate to the third tab and go back to tabs 1 and 2, the content appears again.

I tried to attach/show the fragment, but this didn't help.

any ideas?

This is the content of my tabs, they all look the same. The ViewClass is the same as well. It implements a Fragment for sure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Navigate to 2"
    local:MvxBind="Click NavigateCommand" />
```

Rotation works as expected (if this information makes any difference.)

Comment: what PagerAdapter are you extending from?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar i implemented my own from Android.Support.V4.View.PagerAdapter

Comment: What do you display in tabs 1 and 2? Some code who help us clear the picture

Comment: since the viewpager preloads those 2 fragments, tab 1 to show it, tab 2 in memory for better performance, could it be that i have to "reset" the view pager?

Comment: This is how you can reset the pager http://stackoverflow.com/a/26859567/1939564

Comment: this helps. i tried to clear the pager on the ondestory of the fragment. and this helps to bring back everything when navigating back; but now it crashes during rotation since the activity is already destoryed, when the transaction is commited

Answer (score 0):

Have you set in your fragment with the sliding tab layout  "setOffscreenPageLimit(5)" to your ViewPager?

```
yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

I set this usually in the onCreateView(...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag in onAttach() and onActivityCreated() in fragment. Checking that flag you can display the contents , here no need to set viewpager.setoffscreenlimit

Comment: how do i force it to display it?

Comment: OnAttach is not called for tab 1 when i navigate back. It is called for tab 2, when i navigate 2 it, but it is not shown