# getChildFragmentManager() and viewpager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have the same problem as [Navigating back to FragmentPagerAdapter -> fragments are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672779/navigating-back-to-fragmentpageradapter-fragments-are-empty) but would like some clarification on the solution of using getChildFragmentManager().

This solution uses getChildFragmentManager(), the manager for fragments inside this Fragment(OuterFragment, which has the viewpager).  InnerFragment is a page inside OuterFragment.  When someone clicks the listview in InnerFragment, I want InnerFragment2 to replace InnerFragment.  What do the xml and fragment managers look like?

fragment_outer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

OuterFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_outer, container, false);
vpPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

FragmentManager cfManager = getChildFragmentManager();
adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(cfManager);

vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
return v;
}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return InnerFragment.newInstance(false);
        case 1:
            return InnerFragment.newInstance(true);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

InnerFragment shows up as a fragment inside OuterFragment, which has the viewpager.  InnerFragment has a listview that when clicked, should replace InnerFragment with InnerFragment2.

InnerFragment.java:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
fm = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft = ft.replace(R.id.inner_content,
                InnerFragment2.newInstance(someArg));
ft.commit();
```

This throws an error saying InnerFragment2 does not recognize view R.id.inner_content.

Not only should InnerFragment2 replace InnerFragment, but when InnerFragment2 is shown and it's button is clicked, I want InnerFragment2 replaced with InnerFragment3.  I basically want to use inner_content as an inner container and keep adding fragments to a backstack for appropriate back behavior.

Do I getChildFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager() each time I add to my fragment backstack, what does the xml pattern look like, because having one framelayout in my outerfragment isn't doing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    FragmentManager cfManager=getChildFragmentManager();
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(cfManager);

   // viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new EntertainmentWallpaperFragment(), getString(R.string.title_entertainment_wallpapers));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new EntertainmentMusicFragment(), getString(R.string.title_entertainment_music));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new EntertainmentGamesFragment(), getString(R.string.title_entertainment_games));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new EntertainmentEBooksFragment(), getString(R.string.title_entertainment_ebooks));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new EntertainmentAppsFragment(), getString(R.string.title_entertainment_apps));
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

I hope this helps. I had the same problem where the fragments apear but once you go back they dissapear and find an empty fragent. Commnented the line that I had first implemented which after updating the fragment manager I was able to enjoy free smooth scroll.

Comment: You must never instantiate fragments outside of the `getItem()` call directly, or you will end up with overlapping fragments when both you add new fragments, but the system has also recreated the fragments. Never store a `List<Fragment>` inside a FragmentPagerAdapter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594982/fragment-has-not-been-attached-yet/58605339#58605339