# Fragment has not been attached yet

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

After reading posts on this exception, I can't understand what I need to do to correct this error. Besides, I can't even reproduce it... This happens sometimes on some devices but I don't understand how...

my logs :

```java
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Fragment a has not been attached yet my.app.HostFragment.addFragment
```

HostFragment class :

```java
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.fragment_root_container, fragment)
          .addToBackStack(null)
          .commit()
}
```

MainActivity class :

```java
fun openNewChampionFragment() {
        val hostFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewpager.currentItem) as HostFragment
        hostFragment.addFragment(ChampionFragment.newInstance())
}
```

ViewPager Adapter :

```java
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    private var fragments: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf()

    fun addFragments(fragments: List<Fragment>) {
        this.fragments = fragments.toMutableList()
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }

    fun clearStack(index: Int){
        (fragments[index] as HostFragment).clearAllStack()
    }
}
```

I always call `addFragment` from my `MainActivity` with a new fragment instance (I don't reuse the instance of the old fragments.)

Which fragment has not been attached ? My HostFragment or the new one that i'm trying to add.

Comment: Since you're using `childFragmentManager`, it seems like you're adding a fragment to your fragment. This method must be in some Fragment class, but you say you're calling it from `MainActivity`... what happens if you move that method to `MainActivity` and use `supportFragmentManager` instead of `childFragmentManager`?

Comment: Each HostFragment is a stack of fragment. So i need to use `childFragmentManager`

Comment: So probably your HostFragment is not yet added to your activity, and so it cannot have child fragments. Remember that fragment transactions are asynchronous.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Ben P. thanks. I wiil check this state with the `isAdded`

Comment: `I always call addFragment from my MainActivity with a new fragment instance (I don't reuse the instance of the old fragments.)` sounds like you might want to add some code from MainActivity so that we know what you are actually doing

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i have added the activty code

Comment: You need to post `pagerAdapter.getItem`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ok it's done ! sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app crashes because the implementation of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is incorrect.

> ```
> // private var fragments: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf() // <-- remove this line entirely
> ```

You mustn't keep a list of fragments in your `Fragment*PagerAdapter`, because the system recreates the Fragments, and the one *you'll* be invoking in that list will never actually be added to the FragmentManager.

Something you can do is switch `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `FragmentPagerAdapter`, then you can apply [App crash after activity has been killed in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753099/app-crash-after-activity-has-been-killed-in-background/55754360#55754360) and [How to get elements of fragments created by ViewPager in MainActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279509/how-to-get-elements-of-fragments-created-by-viewpager-in-mainactivity/54280113#54280113) .

To reproduce your crash, refer to [Singleton object becomes null after app is resumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046773/singleton-object-becomes-null-after-app-is-resumed/49107399#49107399) .

Comment: thank you ! I'm able to reproduce the crash with the terminate button. I will try your solution and read the others post !

Comment: I have trouble solving the problem.. Have you done a sample project ?

Comment: You need to use FragmentPagerAdapter and return a new instance of Fragment in getItem.

Comment: Okay! I finally made it ^^ thank you very much... it would have been very complicated to find on my own.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the terminate logcat button does?

Comment: Kill the process, but not force stop. Not sure which command it is from a terminal, though.

Comment: Do you think that it is the entry in doze mode can produce the same effect as the terminate button?

Comment: @ZachBvy I found the command, it's `am kill`, as says in `adb shell am kill com.example.android.codelabs.lifecycle` in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#6

Comment: It does it all the time tbh :D