# Android BottomNavigationView with child of Tabbed ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-bottom-nav-view

I'm using `BottomNavigationView` to navigate between two Fragments, on of these fragments has its own `ViewPager` with `TabLayout` as below:

[image]

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
MainActivity
 |--- HomeFragment
 |           |--- POPULAR
 |           |--- LATEST
 |           |--- TOP RATED
 |           |--- UPCOMING
 |--- FavoritesFragment
```

it works fine while swiping the `ViewPager`, the problem occures when i'm in `LATEST` or `TOP RATED` and navigates the `BottomNavigationView` to  `FavoritesFragment`
and return back to `HomeFragment`, the `ViewPager` starts over from `POPULAR` not the fragment i was in before navigation.

How can i avoid this tricky navigation problem?

And what is the best solution to keep track of navigation in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

[addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addtobackstack)

[Fragment Transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions)

> And what is the best solution to keep track of navigation in such
>   situation?

I am obviously unaware of a best solution. A case like this involves fragment lifecycles as well which further complicate things.
If you want a very specific navigation behaviour - specially the ability to resume from any previous UI state - I would suggest using a log file to keep track of lifecycle and navigation changes. This has often paid off for me in the long run

Comment: I'm using ViewPager so i cannot use addToBackStack

Comment: @iosamammohamed maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672779/navigating-back-to-fragmentpageradapter-fragments-are-empty) might help