# android navigation drawer fragment and ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, extends, android-actionbaractivity

I have a navigation drawer and in one of the fragments, I'm trying to add a tab swipe layout. However I am unable to extend both `ActionBarActivity` and `Fragment`. Everything I've found online talks about `FragmentActivity` and not `Fragment`.

Is their a way to accomplish this?

This is my `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            objFragment = new myPantry_fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new myRecipes_fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new wheel_fragment();
            break;
        case 3:  
            objFragment = new addRecipes_fragment();//this causes errors
         //when I change extends Fragment to extends ActionBarActivity
            break;

    }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4: //added this
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

This is my fragment I access from the navigation drawer.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class addRecipes_fragment extends ActionBarActivity {
View rootview;
ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Nullable
//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addrecipes_layout, container, false); //error shows in video too



    //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); //
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            Log.d("selected: ", "onTabSelected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + " " + tab.getText());
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            Log.d("Unselected: ", "onTabSelected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + " " + tab.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            Log.d("Reselected: ", "onTabSelected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + " " + tab.getText());
        }

    };
    //Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("General").setTabListener(tabListener)); //Android
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Add Ingredients").setTabListener(tabListener)); //IOS
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Add steps").setTabListener(tabListener)); //Windows
    return rootview;
}

}
```

Comment: If you want to Tab in your fragment then you need to use your `MainActivity` `Action bar`  while attach a fragment `onAttach()` method.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Thanks, but I'm not sure where I should edit my code. Do I need to alter onAttach() in the mainActivity?

Comment: no. Not in main activity in your fragment class you need to use action bar of your main activity.

Comment: you can have tab swipe fragment inside a fragment, in which you will have main fragment which will be host for other swipe tab fragment's :)

Comment: @PankajNimgade Just to clarify do you mean to have the fragment accessed from the navigation drawer call another fragment which has the tab fragments

Comment: @Megan, you are absolutely right. Main Activity has a fragment (lets say HostFragment which opens from navigationDrawer) and this fragment will have your tab swipe fragments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your addRecipes_fragment extending the Fragment from support lib. Use a Viewpager in the Fragment layout to display the tabs and a custom PagerAdapter to load them using childfragment manager. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090227/4714139) link.