# Android fragment stackoverflow

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

When I instantiate this fragment I get a stackoverflow error. I'm trying to have this fragment selected using the navigation drawer defined in my main activity class.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_meet, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file page_meet.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00FF00" >


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Logcat wasn't very informative:

```
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11890)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirection(View.java:11892)
10-07 03:19:27.910: E/AndroidRuntime(27875):    at android.view.View.canResolveLayoutDirec
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my answer without realizing you had a `ViewPager` inside the XML for the `Fragment`. Is it your intention for `MyFragment` to contain other `Fragment`s? If not, then this design is not correct. The `ViewPager` belongs in a layout used in the `Activity`. If you do want to show other `Fragment`s inside `MyFragment`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700226/display-fragment-viewpager-within-a-fragment).

Original answer:
Your problem is that you are creating a new `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` in the `onViewCreated` of the `Fragment` itself. The pager adapter should not be an inner class of the `Fragment`. The pager adapter works with the view pager in an `Activity` to determine which type of `Fragment` should be shown at any given time.

Edit:
Just because I saw your comment on the other answer, `getItem` should return a new instance of the `Fragment`. That was not the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I did want MyFragment to contain a ViewPager populated with two other fragments. The stack overflow error was because I called MyFragment.newInstance() recursively without realizing it. I tried populating the view pager with it's own fragment class. I fixed the problem by nesting another fragment class inside and calling its newInstance() method inside getItem().

Completed working code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final MyFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_meet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MeetFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static class MeetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

        public static final MeetFragment newInstance(int position) {
            MeetFragment fragment = new MeetFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;
            int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_meet_0, container, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_meet_1, container, false);
                break;
            default:
                rootView = null;
                break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```