# Android project code structure for app - deailing with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've run into a road block with creating a basic app - due to my understanding of fragments and basic app structure. Could you give me an idea for how my app should be structured?

- I have an app with a navigation drawer (currently in the main activity).
- The main activity layout has the drawerlayout widget, a frame layout (for fragments), and the list view for the drawer.
- Each fragment (or class) is selected thru the navigation drawer.

this has worked fine so far, but I have run into a roadblock. I'd like to create a new fragment which would has tabs. Just about every tutorial I've looked at creates an activity that extends **FragmentActivity** ... this won't work since FragmentActivity is an Activity.

My question is - is the way I'm structuring my app to work wrong? How should I go about implementing this new tabbed activity / fragment?

Please let me know if you need additional details about the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and add a TabStrip on top. The ViewPager can be contained in a separate Fragment, so would meet your requirement.

See this post for further details [Display fragment viewpager within a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700226/display-fragment-viewpager-within-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider launching an activity when an item is selected from the navigation drawer. Just call `startActivity(your_intent)` in the onClick for the navigation drawer item.

This way the new activity can extend **FragmentActivity** as the tutorials suggest.