# add Viewpager dynamically in a framelayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

Is it possible to replace a fragment in a FrameLayout with the `.replace()` to use a ViewPager? since both are ViewGroups.

For example, in xml, I have only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id ="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and I would like to replace the FrameLayout with id content that is holding a fragment to a ViewPager of fragments in runtime. Is it  possible??

Answer (score 4):

> i would like to replace the framelayout with id content that is
>   holding a fragment to a viewpager of fragments in runtime. is it
>   possible??

You can't replace a `Fragment` with a simple `ViewGroup` like a `ViewPager`, but thanks to the new changes in 4.2 you could put the `ViewPager` itself in a `Fragment` and use nested `Fragments` as the children of the `ViewPager`. Then you could replace the initial `Fragment` with the `Fragment` that holds the `ViewPager`.

See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments), nested `Fragments` are also available to lower APIs through the compatibility package. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379194/how-to-add-a-fragment-inside-a-viewpager-using-nested-fragment-android-4-2) for an implementation example.