# Fragment added programmatically disappear

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

My application uses tabs, each tab is `Fragment` (from android.app.Fragment). I want to use nested fragments in one of those.

Here is the top level fragment supposed to contains the nested fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import fr.epitech.test_esi.R;

public class ReservationCalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final int stringId = R.string.calendar_tab;
    public static final String tag = "reservation_calendar_frag";

    CalendarFragment t = new CalendarFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.calendarframelayout, t, CalendarFragment.tag);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.reservation_calendar_layout, null);
    }
}
```

}

It adds programmatically the first fragment using a `FragmentTransaction`. It actually works (i mean, the nested fragment is added and i can see it) but each time i switch to another tab (so another fragment is displayed) and go back to it, the nested fragment has disappeared.

Here is the code of the `CalendarFragment`:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;
import fr.epitech.test_esi.R;

public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String tag = "calendar_frag";

    private SimpleDateFormat _df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, null);
        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) fragView
                .findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                    int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                Log.d("DATE", c.getTime().toString());
            }
        });
        return fragView;
    }
```

- The nested fragment `CalendarFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- My activity is a `FragmentActivity`

I even tried stay on this fragment, put the activity in background (using home button) and resume it, the nested fragment is still displayed. It's really happen when i switch between the tabs of my application.

Comment: When you want nested fragments you use `getChildFragmentmanager()`. `R.id.calendarframelayout` is the id of a view from `R.layout.reservation_calendar_layout` or is the id of the layout where the tabs are positioned? Also, simple tabs or tabs implemented through a `ViewPager`?

Comment: @Luksprog i use tabs in a ViewPager. The R.id.calendarframelayout is the id of the framelayout contained in R.layout.reservation_calendar_layout. Also, how should i use `getChildFragmentManager`? It seems like i can't use it with Fragment from support lib.

Comment: Check this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381792/493939 and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Luksprog atm i'd to be able to use getChildFragmentManager :) i'm working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the fragment in onCreate which would only be called once the fragment is created, create it in onCreateView but check if the fragment is null first

```
public class ReservationCalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final int stringId = R.string.calendar_tab;
    public static final String tag = "reservation_calendar_frag";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CalendarFragment t = (CalendarFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(CalendarFragment.tag);

        if(t == null) {
            t = new CalendarFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.calendarframelayout, t, CalendarFragment.tag);
        ft.commit();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.reservation_calendar_layout, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.epitech.test_esi.fragments.ReservationCalendarFragment.getChildFragmentManager
07-10 17:34:54.321: E/AndroidRuntime(16917):  at fr.epitech.test_esi.fragments.ReservationCalendarFragment.onCreateView(ReservationCalendarFragment.java:27)

Comment: I actually use support library v4.

Comment: I trying using support library v13 but still the same.