# ViewPager of Fragment does not show its content when the root Fragment is replaced again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i'm implementing the `fragment screen` that contains `root view pager` which contains `child fragment` and the first of `child fragment` has a `view pager` which shows images.

it is shown pretty good at first time, but when the `fragment` which contains `root view pager` is removed and replaced again (with new keyword for `fragment screen`), `roow view pager` doesn't show `child fragment`.

here is the portion of my source.

```
    @AfterViews // this is the method of fragment screen
    protected void afterViews() {
        api(HotelDetailAPI.class).getProduct("hotels", getArguments().getInt("itemId"), new Callback<Hotel>(this) {
            @Override
            public void success(Hotel _hotel, Response response) {
                hotel = _hotel;
                HotelDetailPagerAdapter adapter = new HotelDetailPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
                contentViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                contentViewPager.setBackgroundColor(0xffffff);
                super.success(hotel, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                super.failure(error);
                LOG.error("failed");
            }
        });
    }


private class HotelDetailPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

        public HotelDetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putSerializable("hotel", hotel);
            Fragment fragment1 = new HotelDetailReservationFragment_();
            Fragment fragment2 = new HotelDetailReservationFragment_();
            Fragment fragment3 = new HotelDetailReservationFragment_();
            fragment1.setArguments(data);
            fragment2.setArguments(data);
            fragment3.setArguments(data);
            fragments.add(fragment1);
            fragments.add(fragment2);
            fragments.add(fragment3);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }


// this is the first fragment of root view pager it's not shown again.
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_hotel_detail_reservation)
public class HotelDetailReservationFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private Hotel hotel;

    @AfterViews
    public void afterViews() {
        hotel = (Hotel)getArguments().getSerializable("hotel");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getBaseActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new ImageSliderFragment_();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putStringArray("images", hotel.getImages());
        fragment.setArguments(data);
        ft.add(R.id.hotel_detail_image_slider_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

note that `fragment screen` is popped from back stack when the user presses back button, and if the user is clicked item again, new instance of `fragment screen is replaced`
what's wrong with them?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841117/4797289

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem from myself.

Fundamentally, it's not good design using fragment like a activity. 
Even if `fragment screen` is removed and destroyed, the children fragments of `fragment screen` are not destroyed.

In my problem, children of the first `fragment screen` was not destroyed, so my pager adapter reuses children again. this causes wrong behavior of view pager.

there is various solution for this problem.

you can destroy all children fragment of `fragment screen` when the `fragment screen` is being destroyed.

or just change `fragment screen` to `Activity`.

i have applied last method, it works well :D

have a good time :D thank you for up voting my question.

Answer (score 42):

Instead of :

```
HotelDetailPagerAdapter adapter = new HotelDetailPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

Try :

```
HotelDetailPagerAdapter adapter = new HotelDetailPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

and

Instead of :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getBaseActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Try :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: I have added 1 more modification. Try with changing that also.

Comment: unbelievable. i had a fragment that was hosting a viewpager.  i had to pass the adapter for that viewpager a getChildFragmentManager or else nothing showed up.  thanks alot for your post.

Comment: You save my day

Comment: Unbelievable. Fragment handling is so tough for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that you have nested fragments and use getFragmentManager();
You should use **getChildFragmentManager()** instead.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391359/1635488

Comment: yes, when u want to show the pager adapter in fragment then you have to use getChildFragmentManger(), instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() in fragment