# Reload or refresh list fragment when swiped or when tab is selected?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-pageradapter

i am unable to reload/refresh Listfragment (**CfFragment(),PfFragment(),IfFragment()** in my below code) when tab is selected or swiped, can any one tell me where i am going wrong.My code is working well when it is created for the first time but it doesn't reload/refresh when swiped or selected.If i change anything in the 1st listfragment it should affect in the 2nd list fragment and so on...
Please can any one help me out.it would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

```
 public class busy extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {


SessionManager session;

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
static ServiceURL URL;

static AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.busy);      

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());              

    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    //mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new CfFragment();
        case 1:
            return new PfFragment();
        case 2:
            return new IfFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Confy";

        case 1:
            return "Peny";

        case 2:
            return "Incy";

        default:

            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: all three fragments are reloaded/refreshed only at the time of creation,i modified a list item in first fragment and its not affecting the second fragment.it is still remains the same.

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive your `AppSectionsPagerAdapter` class as

```
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

instead of

```
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Basically, `FragmentPagerAdapter` keeps the created `Fragment`s in memory, while `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` destroys and creates them anew as they are shifted in and out of view.

Two more things:

**1.** Make sure you are *not* calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in any of your  `Fragment`s, else they won't be recreated.

**2.** Add

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

to your code.

**EDIT:**

Instead of

```
Activity -> ViewPager -> Fragments
```

create the structure as

```
Activity -> Fragment -> ViewPager -> Nested Fragments
```

This will ensure that each `Fragment` is refreshed on tab change. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379194/how-to-add-a-fragment-inside-a-viewpager-using-nested-fragment-android-4-2) post for the implementation.

Comment: i have added as you said,but it is still remains the same...and i am not calling setRetainInstance(true) any where in that fragment...where am i going wrong?