# How to reload / refresh fragment that has already been displayed once?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-sqlite

[image]

- I have 2 `Fragment`s: `My1stFragment` and `My2ndFragment`.
- Inside `My1stFragment` I have a `ListView` which is populated by database. Also when I click on edit button I call 2nd `Fragment` to edit data.
- In 2nd `Fragment` I edit my salary amount and update my database by clicking on submit button and come back to `My1stFragment`.
- The problem is when I come back to `My1stFragment`, my `ListView` is not updated, even though the database has been updated.

Comment: are you using a cursor loader?

Comment: i am getting data but i can not refresh List View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derive your `PagerAdapter` class as

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

instead of

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Basically, `FragmentPagerAdapter` keeps the created `Fragment`s in memory, while `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` destroys and creates them anew as they are shifted in and out of view.

**Further Considerations:**

**1.** Make sure you are *not* calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in any of your  `Fragment`s, else they won't be refreshed / updated.

**2.** Add

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

to your code. This ensures that adjacent `Fragment`s are recreated.

**3.** Instead of

```
Activity -> ViewPager -> Fragments
```

create the structure as

```
Activity -> Fragment -> ViewPager -> Nested Fragments
```

This will ensure that each `Fragment` is refreshed on page swipe. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379194/how-to-add-a-fragment-inside-a-viewpager-using-nested-fragment-android-4-2) for the implementation.

**EDIT:**

As discussed in the comments below, point 2 is redundant. So only points 1 and 3 are actually useful in this case.

Comment: sure of the second point? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56667#c3. By default its 1!.

Comment: great point, very good :) I suppose the second recommendation is redundant, as the minimum is internally set to 1.

Comment: @ Y.S Thanks for helping its easy to understand and implement also i refer this simple, easy and good one.

Answer (score 5):

Add following in your firstFragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        Log.e("Visible hint","in visibleHint ()");
        //add your method to set adapter to listview here by passing (getActivity().getApplicationContext()) parameter for context
    }
}
```

Now when you want to come to first fragment from other fragment, use :

```
((ActivityOfFragment) getActivity())./*viewPager if any.*/setCurrentItem(0/*fragment position*/, true);
```

Comment: @RamMansawala Pleasure:)

Comment: Now it's depricated!