# Start child fragment in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm using `ViewPager2` with `FragmentStateAdapter`. Basic 3 fragments (A-B-C). It means, you can scroll from A to B, B to C

**What I want to do?**

From fragment B start child fragment D

`(A-B-C)
    | 
    D`

From fragment B start fragment D, when the user click "back arrow" (top bar), fragment D will be destroyed and the user will back to B. (I don't want to use activity)

**What I tried?**

```
val ft: FragmentTransaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, DetailsFragment())
ft.addToBackStack(null)
ft.commit();
```

With the code above I have two issues.

1. Two fragments (B and created D) overlap (I see B and D at the same time)
2. When clicking back button (on top bar), neither fragment B or D won't close

Edit:
Passing fragment manager to `ViewPager2`, in main_activity in onCreate() method

```
pagerAdapter = PagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
binding.mainViewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
```

PagerAdapter is a simple class:
`class PagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle)`

Comment: Where you init viewpageradapter in fragment or activity?

Comment: Show me what fragment manager you pass to your adapter

Comment: @CôngHải updated

Comment: 1. You should use add instead of replace. 2. Make sure you set background for content view DetailFragment. When you set background it doesnt overlap. 3. What method when you press back button top bar? You should call activity?.onBackPress()

Comment: Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67269776/14993809) where I answer this question

Answer (score 3):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` insead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I have the same result, but I have to change `android.R.id.content` to `R.id.main` which is main container of `MasterFragment()` (B) (because I've got error "could not find `android.R.id.content` in details fragment")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391359/9523118  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381792/9523118 there is already answers available

Comment: it's not a old solution for viewpager v 1.0?

Comment: Because documantation says 'use FragmentStateAdapter' when u use version 2.0

Comment: yes. you are right. You need to replace your main container from your ViewPager Fragment using listener.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer for going detail fragment from a ViewPager's fragment as question states.

I also made it a little bit complicated by putting viewPager into a fragment, you can skip and add it to activity if you wish.

1. Create a layout for Activity

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`FragmentContainerView` contains the fragment that has `ViewPager2`

```
//  Replace Fragment with DSL style
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        replace<FragmentThatContainsViewPager>(R.id.fragment_container_view)

    }
```

FragmentThatContainsViewPager's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Code for container fragment

```
class FragmentThatContainsViewPager : BaseDataBindingFragment<FragmentWithViewpagerBinding>() {

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_with_viewpager
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // TabLayout
        val tabLayout = dataBinding.tabLayout
        // ViewPager2
        val viewPager = dataBinding.viewPager

        /*
             Set Adapter for ViewPager inside this fragment using this Fragment,
            more specifically childFragmentManager as param
         */
        viewPager.adapter = ChildFragmentStateAdapter(this)

        // Bind tabs and viewpager
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = "Tab $position"
        }.attach()

    }

}
```

Adapter of ViewPager, you can use GenericFragmentParent.newInstance() if you wish i used `FragmentFactory`

class ChildFragmentStateAdapter(private val fragment: Fragment) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

```
private val genericFragmentFactory = GenericFragmentFactory.getFragmentFactory()


override fun getItemCount(): Int = 5

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

    genericFragmentFactory.fragID = position

    return genericFragmentFactory.instantiate(
        fragment.requireActivity().classLoader,
        GenericFragmentParent::class.java.name
    )
}
```

}

```
class GenericFragmentParent(private val fragID: Int) :
    BaseDataBindingFragment<FragmentGenericParentBinding>() {


    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_generic_parent
    }



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        dataBinding.btnNextPage.setOnClickListener {

            /*
                 Replacing in container in Activity for both fragments to
                be in same stack of supportFragmentManager
             */
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
                replace<GenericChildFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Also used back stack count to display back arrow on top

```
  supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {

            val fragmentOnTop = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
                R.id.fragment_container_view
            )

            val fragmentCount = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount

            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(fragmentCount > 0)

        }
```

And

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    return true
}
```

to remove fragment when back arrow is touched.

I added sample [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials), it's in MaterialDesign module, probably add another example for navigation for child fragments of ViewPager tabs each with their own child fragments instead of opening detail fragment
while you can swipe neighbor fragments of ViewPager2